# How to get value from popup window to parent window by clicking from database selection?

Tags: javascript

I need advice on how to get the selected value from the popup window to the parent window by clicking on the database selection.
my parental window is as follows:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
var retVal=""
var valReturned;
function openModal() {
    retVal = window.open("stranky/modal.php", "_blank", "width=950,height=600");
    valReturned=retVal;
    document.getElementById("zakaznik").value=valReturned;
    //alert('The following text has been returned: "'+valReturned+'"');
}
```

```
                <tr>
                    <td>Zákazník:</td>
                    <td><input id="zakaznik" type="text" name="zakaznik" value="">&nbsp;<input class="odeslat" type="button" name="vybrat" value="Vybrat" onclick="openModal()"></td>
                </tr>
```

---

in popup window (modal.php) I have this:

```
<td><a href="#" onclick="returnValue='.$data["id"].';window.close();">'.$data["id"].'</a></td>
```

window will open to me normally, I can click on the selected value from the database - after clicking on the selected field will close the window, but the form field zakaznik in the parent window does not get the value, only when opening the popup window will form [object Window] zakaznik. I think I miss something, and I think it's wrong. could someone advise what it should look like?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

OnClick event in your popup window should reference callBack function.

```
<td><a href="#" onclick="returnValue(<?php echo $data["id"]?>);window.close();"></a></td>
```

And in your main page you should define the callback function.

```
returnValue(popUpValue){
  alert("Got popup value! : " + popUpValue)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Originally it was like this and it worked until the crawlers no longer supported it, and even the return No. after the click I got there:

```
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
var retVal=""
var valReturned;
function openModal() {
    retVal=showModalDialog('stranky/modal.php');
    valReturned=retVal;
    document.getElementById("zakaznik").value=valReturned;
   }</script>


<td><input id="zakaznik" type="text" name="zakaznik" value="'.$_POST["zakaznik"].'">&nbsp;<input class="odeslat" type="button" name="vybrat" value="Vybrat" onClick="openModal()"></td>
```

In the modal window it clicked only this way and it worked and it works even in the historical version of the web browser to this day, but new browsers do not open it anymore:

```
<td><a href="#" onclick="returnValue='.$data["id"].';window.close();">'.$data["id"].'</a></td>
```

Unfortunately, I can not modify it to work in new browsers, and therefore please advice: just click on a value and it transferred and the window clicked the value itself closed.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o6UsE.png)

Well, I really don't know how, I can't figure it out, I'm not good at this, so I'd like someone to write an example of what it should look like. I don't know where to put those terms. Thank you.